# How to return generated ID with Fluent Data Access API in Spring Data R2DBC

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

My database automatically generate IDs when new records are inserted, and I want to use the generated ID in my code once the insertion completed. When using `Statement`, it can be achieved by the [following approach](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#r2dbc.datbaseclient.filter).

```kotlin
db.execute("INSERT INTO table (name, state) VALUES(:name, :state)")
    .filter { s, next -> next.execute(s.returnGeneratedValues("id")) }
    .bind("name", name)
    .bind("state", state)
    .map { t -> t.get("id", Long::class.java) }
```

However, I am using [Fluent Data Access API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#r2dbc.datbaseclient.fluent-api.insert) currently, thus an approach to get inserted ID in the following code style will be appreciated in my case.

```kotlin
db.insert().into("table")
    .value("name", name)
    .value("state", state)
    // get generated ID
```

Is there any solution to achieve so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the same `map` method:

```kotlin
db.insert().into("test")
    .value("name", name)
    .value("state", state)
    // Use "LAST_INSERTED_ID" for MySQL
    .map { t -> t.get("id", java.lang.Long::class.java) }
    .one()
```

(I'm assuming the generated ID column in the table is called `id`)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it, however, the generated ID didn't return but the following exception.
`java.util.NoSuchElementException: column name 'id' does not exist in [LAST_INSERT_ID]`
By the way, I am using `dev.miku:r2dbc-mysql` combined with MySQL 5.7

Comment: Hmm, I've tested it with H2 and Postgres,  so it''s apparently MySQL driver issue.

Comment: Try changing 'id' to 'LAST_INSERTED_ID'  in the map lambda.